# Geolocation from jpeg in java

Tags: java, geolocation, struts

My friend is using Struts (Java) and we are trying to find the GeoLocation of a JPEG picture.

I have no idea where to read or how to implement the java code for it.

I want to get an image in jpeg form and have it shows on google maps on a website.

How do you pass those information from Exif tags to Google Map so i can see the location on the Map

Comment: The Geolocation is in the EXIF tags. Try to get it yourself, google gives me quite a few results how to extract EXIF information from JPEG. If you've got a more specific question ask again or refine your question.

Answer (score 2):

The geolocation part has nothing to do with Struts. Struts is only involved in the presentation of the data.

The geolocation of an image is *sometimes* stored in the metadata of a JPEG file. You can use a library like [this one](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) to extract metadata from a JPEG image.

Be aware that many cameras don't store the geolocation data.

Comment: OH they don't, then what is my prof talking about. My Prof Asked us to do a projects and now we are stuck with something that we have no idea about it yet, Let me read your library page, and see if that make sense to me at all Thanx

Comment: How do you pass those information from Exif tags to Google Map do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to research it for yourself. If you have looked everywhere and you are still stuck, you can open another question here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 parts

1. Extracting gps information from Jpeg Image
2. How to give the extracted information to google maps.

This elaborately discusses the first part

Reading Image Meta is now much simpler and streamlined with [apache commons-imaging library](https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging)

```
/**
 * Reference : https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/MetadataExample.java
 */
public static void readImageMeta(final File imgFile) throws ImageReadException, IOException {
    /** get all metadata stored in EXIF format (ie. from JPEG or TIFF). **/
    final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(imgFile);
    System.out.println(metadata);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    
    /** Get specific meta data information by drilling down the meta **/
    if (metadata instanceof JpegImageMetadata) {
        JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
        
        // simple interface to GPS data
        final TiffImageMetadata exifMetadata = jpegMetadata.getExif();
        if (null != exifMetadata) {
            final TiffImageMetadata.GPSInfo gpsInfo = exifMetadata.getGPS();
            if (null != gpsInfo) {
                final String gpsDescription = gpsInfo.toString();
                final double longitude = gpsInfo.getLongitudeAsDegreesEast();
                final double latitude = gpsInfo.getLatitudeAsDegreesNorth();

                System.out.println("    " + "GPS Description: " + gpsDescription);
                System.out.println("    " + "GPS Longitude (Degrees East): " + longitude);
                System.out.println("    " + "GPS Latitude (Degrees North): " + latitude);
            }
        }

        // more specific example of how to manually access GPS values
        final TiffField gpsLatitudeRefField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        final TiffField gpsLatitudeField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        final TiffField gpsLongitudeRefField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
        final TiffField gpsLongitudeField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
        if (gpsLatitudeRefField != null && gpsLatitudeField != null && gpsLongitudeRefField != null && gpsLongitudeField != null) {
            // all of these values are strings.
            final String gpsLatitudeRef = (String) gpsLatitudeRefField.getValue();
            final RationalNumber[] gpsLatitude = (RationalNumber[]) (gpsLatitudeField.getValue());
            final String gpsLongitudeRef = (String) gpsLongitudeRefField.getValue();
            final RationalNumber[] gpsLongitude = (RationalNumber[]) gpsLongitudeField.getValue();

            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeDegrees = gpsLatitude[0];
            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeMinutes = gpsLatitude[1];
            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeSeconds = gpsLatitude[2];

            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeDegrees = gpsLongitude[0];
            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeMinutes = gpsLongitude[1];
            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeSeconds = gpsLongitude[2];

            // This will format the gps info like so:
            //
            // gpsLatitude: 8 degrees, 40 minutes, 42.2 seconds S
            // gpsLongitude: 115 degrees, 26 minutes, 21.8 seconds E

            System.out.println("    " + "GPS Latitude: " + gpsLatitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, " + gpsLatitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, " + gpsLatitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds " + gpsLatitudeRef);
            System.out.println("    " + "GPS Longitude: " + gpsLongitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, " + gpsLongitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, " + gpsLongitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds " + gpsLongitudeRef);
        }
    }
}

private static void printTagValue(final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata, TagInfo tagInfo) {
    final TiffField field = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(tagInfo);
    if (field == null) {
        System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": " + "Not Found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": " + field.getValueDescription());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
    File sourceFile = new File("/Users/vivek/myimage.jpg");
    readImageMeta(sourceFile);
}
```

The above code will give this output

```
Exif metadata:
    Root: 
        ImageWidth: 3024
        ImageLength: 4032
        BitsPerSample: 8, 8, 8
        PhotometricInterpretation: 2
        Make: 'Apple'
        Model: 'iPhone 6s'
        Orientation: 1
        SamplesPerPixel: 3
        XResolution: 72
        YResolution: 72
        ResolutionUnit: 2
        Software: 'Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 (Macintosh)'
        DateTime: '2016:05:17 16:55:55'
        YCbCrPositioning: 1
        ExifOffset: 300
        GPSInfo: 868

    Exif: 
        ExposureTime: 1/100 (0.01)
        FNumber: 11/5 (2.2)
        ExposureProgram: 2
        PhotographicSensitivity: 40
        ExifVersion: 48, 50, 50, 49
        DateTimeOriginal: '2016:05:08 18:03:57'
        DateTimeDigitized: '2016:05:08 18:03:57'
        ComponentsConfiguration: 1, 2, 3, 0
        ShutterSpeedValue: 35113/5284 (6.645)
        ApertureValue: 7983/3509 (2.275)
        BrightnessValue: 13026/2395 (5.439)
        ExposureCompensation: 0
        MeteringMode: 5
        Flash: 16
        FocalLength: 83/20 (4.15)
        SubjectArea: 618, 1555, 310, 311
        SubSecTimeOriginal: '523'
        SubSecTimeDigitized: '523'
        FlashpixVersion: 48, 49, 48, 48
        ColorSpace: 1
        ExifImageWidth: 3024
        ExifImageLength: 4032
        SensingMethod: 2
        SceneType: 1
        CustomRendered: 4
        ExposureMode: 0
        WhiteBalance: 0
        FocalLengthIn35mmFormat: 29
        SceneCaptureType: 0
        LensSpecification: 83/20 (4.15), 83/20 (4.15), 11/5 (2.2), 11/5 (2.2)
        LensMake: 'Apple'
        LensModel: 'iPhone 6s back camera 4.15mm f/2.2'

    Gps: 
        GPSLatitudeRef: 'N'
        GPSLatitude: 13, 21, 3305/100 (33.05)
        GPSLongitudeRef: 'E'
        GPSLongitude: 75, 33, 2034/100 (20.34)
        GPSAltitudeRef: 0
        GPSAltitude: 83651/95 (880.537)
        GPSTimeStamp: 12, 33, 57
        GPSSpeedRef: 'K'
        GPSSpeed: 21/100 (0.21)
        GPSImgDirectionRef: 'T'
        GPSImgDirection: 1654/31 (53.355)
        GPSDestBearingRef: 'T'
        GPSDestBearing: 1654/31 (53.355)
        GPSDateStamp: '2016:05:08'
        Unknown Tag (0x1f): 5

    Sub:  (jpegImageData)
        Compression: 6
        XResolution: 72
        YResolution: 72
        ResolutionUnit: 2
        JpgFromRawStart: 1274
        JpgFromRawLength: 8211

Photoshop (IPTC) metadata:
        Date Created: 20160508
        Time Created: 180357+0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GPSLatitudeRef: 'N'
GPSLatitude: 13, 21, 3305/100 (33.05)
GPSLongitudeRef: 'E'
GPSLongitude: 75, 33, 2034/100 (20.34)
    GPS Description: [GPS. Latitude: 13 degrees, 21 minutes, 33.05 seconds N, Longitude: 75 degrees, 33 minutes, 20.34 seconds E]
    GPS Longitude (Degrees East): 75.55565
    GPS Latitude (Degrees North): 13.359180555555556
    GPS Latitude: 13 degrees, 21 minutes, 33.05 seconds N
    GPS Longitude: 75 degrees, 33 minutes, 20.34 seconds E
```

For more refer to the library documentation [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html)
Maven Repo Link [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging).
Note : It's an alpha release at this time but you can trust apache :D.

Cheers!